# storing values without automatically linking to the page

Tags: php

Is there a way where I can transfer these input values without automatically going into the next page.

```
        <form method="GET" action="cos2.php">
<td> Table:</td>
<td>
<select name="table"><option value=""></option>
<option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option
</select>
    </form>
```

The values will be shown into "cos2.php". But I want to store it on "cos2.php" page without automatically going to the "cos2.php" page.

Comment: you can use ajax for this

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `jQuery.ajax()` there are tons of tutorial for doing this.

**Example**

**HTML:**

```
<form id="foo">

    <label for="bar">A bar</label>
    <input id="bar" name="bar" type="text" value="" />

    <input type="submit" value="Send" />

</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
// variable to hold request
var request;
$("#foo").submit(function(event){
    // abort any pending request
    if (request) {
        request.abort();
    }
    // setup some local variables
    var $form = $(this);
    // let's select and cache all the fields
    var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");
    // serialize the data in the form
    var serializedData = $form.serialize();

    // let's disable the inputs for the duration of the ajax request
    $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

    // fire off the request to /form.php
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "/form.php",
        type: "post",
        data: serializedData
    });

    // callback handler that will be called on success
    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        // log a message to the console
        console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
    });

    // callback handler that will be called on failure
    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // log the error to the console
        console.error(
            "The following error occured: "+
            textStatus, errorThrown
        );
    });

    // callback handler that will be called regardless
    // if the request failed or succeeded
    request.always(function () {
        // reenable the inputs
        $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
    });

    // prevent default posting of form
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

**PHP (i.e. form.php):**

```
// you can access the values posted by jQuery.ajax
// through the global variable $_POST, like this:
$bar = $_POST['bar'];
```

and you are done.

Comment: http://www.queness.com/post/160/create-a-ajax-based-form-submission-with-jquery see the links that will show more of this..

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Jquery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for this there many example of these.